# postion:fixed no scrolling on mobiles

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am having some troubles here:  http://test30.hscreativedev.co.uk/index2.html

When the width of the window reduces (`@media (max-width: 768px)` it is impossible to scroll down and read all the text.

So far, I've tried `overflow-y: scroll` but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestion? `Min-height: 100%` on that div won't work.

Thank you very much.

Comment: that's some really messy code for a page that simple.

Comment: @vlrprbttst you are right. I am a complete beginner.

Comment: no offense, just consider refining your html. a simple html leads to less bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if you meant to do this, but you've got your content on `position: fixed` and the background scrollable.

You'll need to remove the `position: fixed` on the content container and add it to the background instead.

EDIT:

If you want to have your text over the image as you have currently, either change the picture of the woman to a `background-image` on the `inner-cover` or `cover-container` divs or add `position: absolute` to your content and add `top: Ypx`, Y being the distance from the top of the page.

Comment: hi there! thank you so much! Changing the position of the text to absolute was enough!